# Missing script: "dev" and localhost:8080 failed to access in m1 macbook air

Tags: vue.js, localhost

I am a new developer to Vue. When I establish a new Vue project, It shows the below error.

```
 npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
 npm ERR!   npm run
```

However, I have such a script in the package.json. It shows:

```
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
        "start": "npm run dev",
        "unit": "jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage",
        "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
        "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
        "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit test/e2e/specs",
        "build": "node build/build.js"
      },
```

Could anyone tell me how to solve the problem?

In addition, my localhost:80 could be accessed but localhost:8080 failed. Could anyone tell me how to solve the problem?

Comment: Please check, that you are in the same directory as the package.json

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested what version of vue are you using, Vue 2 and below uses such scripts in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```

You can repace "serve" with "dev" so you could run `npm run dev`

and yes, check where is the package.json file, it must be right inside your project folder on same level as scr, node_modules folders

Comment: hi, the version of vue is 2.9.6. I have tried to use your code but it cannot work yet. Do I need to install another version of vue?

Comment: thats really strange, there can be some scripts missing, have you tryed to re-create athe project?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. My installation was wrong. The problem has been solved. The installation method is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TY6TGrHTxMM